# Angular2 Reactive Form Validation Error control.registerOnChange is not a function

Tags: angular2-forms

Here im Implementin Simple AngularForm using Angular2

```
export class Customer  { customerName: String = "";}
```

I imported this cla in My Compnent class

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core"
import { NgForm, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms"
import { Customer } from "../template/customer"

@Component({
    selector: "ui-view",
    templateUrl: "../template/customer.html"
})

    export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {
        currentCustomer: Customer = null;
        customerForm: FormGroup;
        custobj: Customer = new Customer();
        ngOnInit(): void {
            this.customerForm = new FormGroup({
                customerName: new FormGroup({

                })
            })
        }
```

My Html code is  im getting Errror as Add formControlName is something...im confusing where i'm doing mistake please help me

```
<form [formGroup]="customerForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="customerName" />
    </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" [disabled]="!customerForms.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```